# Set thumbnail and title for a post type archive (not post itself!)

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin, custom-post-type-archives

I know it is easy to add custom fields (meta boxes) to custom post types POSTS. And also I know that if you want to add thumbnail to a post type you should add support for it in `register_post_type`. but how it is done with custom post type itself (Archive)?

PS: I have read the documentation of `register_post_type` but found nothing.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Comment: wouldn't it be better if you say how I'm wrong instead of giving me thumb down?!

Comment: If you review the WordPress documentation on register_post_type() the majority of your question will be answered. You can find that on the WordPress codex at https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Comment: @Stephen I think you have miss understood my friend. I do not need a thumbnail for posts, I want it for the archive and it seems that it is impossible with register_post_type

Comment: perhaps you should edit your question to clarify and ask a specific question. As it reads it simply looks as if you haven't bothered to read the basic documentation on CPT.

Comment: @Stephen So I will say that I have bothered to read the whole documentation :))

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
 $args = array( 'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
    );
```

This code goes after the function that creates your CPT and before the register_post_type

i.e.

```
function my_custom_post () {
...
}

$args = array (...)
);

register_post_type ($cpt, $args);
```

Comment: thanks but no my friend, I want the thumbnail for the Archive, not for the posts.

Comment: I know, but I get it when my answer was published :P

Do you have custom taxonomies?

What do you have in this line

`'taxonomies' => array(...),`

Comment: It has some taxonomies but I think it has no use for this

Comment: I've checked on a template of mine and I did it naming the archive page `archive-my_custom_post.php ` and this `<?php the_post_thumbnail('category-thumbnail'); ?>` (the CPT uses default categories).

Would you share your problem code?
`

Answer (score 1):

Archives themselves are not defined using the register_post_type() function, they are simply a display or list of a given post type using the theme's archive page(s) or custom archive page format. The display of a thumbnail or featured image is controlled by the theme or custom archive page(s).

If a CPT is registered to support categories then a thumbnail or featured image can be defined for the given category of the custom post type. But again the display of that category thumbnail is determined by the theme or custom archive page. Not within the CPT itself.

Comment: And by "page" I believe you mean the archive template, or PHP script used to display that archive page.